# Clicking non Vuetify button does not update data in v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

In the code pen I have two buttons. One Vuetify and the other not. both should call the `updateData()` function but only the Vuetify component is able to run it succesfully. How can I call the method defined in the component from outside the `app` div?

https://codepen.io/entropy283/pen/rNxMXGX?editors=1010

Comment: Any specific reason on why you don't want to place the button just inside your app-div and use @click?

Comment: I am trying to migrate an old app and would rather do it in steps instead of just changing everything. I know it's a really weird problem, haha sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to trigger `updateData` method, which is accessible only inside the HTML element that Vue is mounted on. I assume you are mounting Vue to the element with `id="app"`.

You have to put the button inside the `<div id="app">`:

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="updateData()">Button</button>
  ...
```

Or, if you don't need to access any Vue properties, you can just create a function inside `script` and trigger it with `onclick` event. Keep in mind that `@click` is also not accessible outside of Vue:

```html
<button onclick="updateData()">Button</button>

<div id="app">
  ...
```

```js
<script>
function updateData() {
  console.log('test')
}
</script>
```